# Condiciones if, else if en java

Tags: java

Soy nuevo en este tema de Java y me tope con un problema, tengo un formulario donde género reportes PDF en el cual tengo varias opciones para generarlos, reporte completo de la tabla, reporte detallado por fecha, reporte con solo por una búsqueda utilizando sentencias SQL LIKE y reportes por columnas de la tabla, bueno en fin ya logre generar los reportes y consultas, el problemas es que solo tengo un botón para generar los 4 reportes de maneras diferentes, dependiendo de los datos que introduzca en las cajas de texto(String, todo los datos son de este tipo).

¿Como hago la condición para seleccionar el reporte adecuado dependiendo de lo que introduzca en las cajas de texto?

Esta es la condición que utilizo

```
String a = funciones.getFecha(fechad);
String b = funciones.getFecha(fechaa);
String c = txtbusqueda.getText();

if ((a != null) && (!a.equals("")) && (b != null) && (!b.equals("")) && (c!=null) && (!c.equals(""))) {
mi reporte 1
}
else if ((c != null) && (!c.equals(""))) {
    reporte2
}
else{
    reporte3
}
```

Solo quiero evaluar si las variables contienen valores o no pero no sé como :'(

Comment: Pero cual seria el problema?

Comment: Cuando le paso datos a las variables y recorre las condiciones no funciona

Comment: que quiere decir no funciona?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo que he entendido en tu pregunta podrías solucionarlo más o menos así:

```
 String a = funciones.getFecha(fechad);
    String b = funciones.getFecha(fechaa);
    String c = txtbusqueda.getText();

    if (hasValue(c)){
        if (hasValue(a) && hasValue(b)){
            reporteQuerySQLConFechas;
        }else{
            reporteQuerySQL;
        }
    }else{
        if (hasValue(a) || hasValue(b)){
            reporteFechas;
        }else{
            reporteTabla;
        }
    }
```

Y la función hasValue la crearía así para que el código quede mucho más claro.

```
private boolean hasValue(String myString){
    return (myString != null) && (!myString.equals(""));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En java el operador "==" prueba si los dos operandos se refieren al mismo objeto, es decir:

```
String x = "HOLA";
String y = new String(new char[] { 'H', 'O', 'L', 'A'});
```

Evaluación ( x == y ) ->Falso

Te recomiendo usar los métodos `contains` y `equals`.
`equals` evalua si existe una equidad, es decir si son "iguales"

```
String x = "HOLA";
String y = new String(new char[] { 'H', 'O', 'L', 'A'});
```

Evaluación ( x.equals(y) ) ->Verdadero

Te recomiendo leer: https://www.arquitecturajava.com/comparando-java-vs-equals/

En tu ejemplo:

```
string MiResultado = funciones.getFecha(fechad);
```

Si quiero que se genere el reporte REPORTE 1 cuando MiResultado sea "RESULTADO1"

```
if(MiResultado.equals("RESULTADO1"))
{
  REPORTE1();
}
```

Si quiero que se genere el REPORTE2 cuando MiResultado **contenga** "RESULTADO2"

```
if(MiResultado.contains("RESULTADO2 y también el RESULTADO3"))
{
  REPORTE3();
}
```

Ten en cuenta que al añadir if pero no else se evaluarán ambos casos. Si tu quieres que el caso sea único añade else antes del segundo if

Answer (score 0):

```
Ya lo resolví, muchas gracias a todo pos su apoyo.
```

:)

```
private void btnPDFActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    String a = funciones.getFecha(fechad);
    String b = funciones.getFecha(fechaa);
    String e = txtbusqueda.getText();

    try {

        if (e.isEmpty()) {
         if (b==null && a==null)  {
                JasperReport reporte = null;
                reporte = null;
                String path = "src\\Report\\reportv.jasper";

                reporte = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(path);

                JasperPrint jprint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte, null, cc);

                JasperViewer view = new JasperViewer(jprint, false);

                view.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

                view.setVisible(true);


            } else {
                JasperReport reporte = null;
                reporte = null;
                String path = "src\\Report\\refortfacha.jasper";
                Map parametro = new HashMap();
                parametro.put("fechadesde", a);
                parametro.put("fechahatsa", b);

                reporte = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(path);

                JasperPrint jprint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte, parametro, cc);

                JasperViewer view = new JasperViewer(jprint, false);

                view.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

                view.setVisible(true);

            }

        }  else {
            if(!e.isEmpty()) {
                if (b==null && a==null){
            JasperReport reporte = null;
            reporte = null;
            String path = "src\\Report\\ReportIndividual.jasper";
            Map parametro = new HashMap();
            parametro.put("valor", e);

            reporte = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(path);

            JasperPrint jprint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte, parametro, cc);

            JasperViewer view = new JasperViewer(jprint, false);

            view.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

            view.setVisible(true);
            }else{
                    JasperReport reporte = null;
                reporte = null;
                String path = "src\\Report\\refortfacha.jasper";
                Map parametro = new HashMap();
                parametro.put("fechadesde", a);
                parametro.put("fechahatsa", b);

                reporte = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(path);

                JasperPrint jprint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte, parametro, cc);

                JasperViewer view = new JasperViewer(jprint, false);

                view.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

                view.setVisible(true);
                }

            }
        } 


        // >:v

    } catch (JRException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Inicio.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


}
```